# reactivity with vue 3 in select component

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, rendering

let me explain to you, when I select an optional element in a select component, it does not show me the selected display, why?

It is worth mentioning that if the data in the json changes

First here is the selected code

```
<SelectComponent
        storeName="selectedOriginCountryOption"
        :activeSelect="generalTerms.selectedOriginCountryOption"
        :title="originCountry.title"
        classDescription="col-4"
        :options="destinyCountry.options"  // <--- 'Here I bring the options'
      />
```

`Then how the Select Component component works from behind is as follows:`

```
const { generalTerms, payments } = useQuotationStore()

const selectedDestinyCountryOption = ref(generalTerms.selectedDestinyCountryOption)

const handleSelection = (valueSelected: string, storeName: nameSelectType) => {
  if (props.section === 'payments') {
    return ((payments as { [key: string]: unknown })[storeName] = valueSelected)
  }


  if (props.section === 'generalTerms') {
    selectedDestinyCountryOption.value = valueSelected
    console.log(selectedDestinyCountryOption.value)  // <--- Here it shows me the selected value
    return ((generalTerms as { [key: string]: unknown })[storeName] = valueSelected)
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="dropdown" :class="['responsive-dropdown', classDescription]">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      {{ activeSelect === '' ? title : activeSelect }}
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li v-for="option in options" :key="option.id">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" @click="handleSelection(option.country, storeName)">
          {{ option.country }}
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

To give you an idea I show you an image of how they work, if I select an element it shows me in the browser console but the display is not seen in the select.

[shows the selected element in the console, except in the select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjJSd.png)

I already tried to refer to the value of selectedDestinyCountryOption assigned to it as a reference,
and even then the visual value does not change in the select

Answer (score 0):

Well, answering my question, a solution is to create a custom event notifying the parent that there is a change within the valueSelected value, indicating to the parent to be able to make the change visually.